# Where can I find the original source code of my c++ vb app?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

A few months ago I coded an app in c++ Visual Studio 2017, and it ran perfectly, and it ran with an original code written by me, very simple and quite basic, which took some time to do, unfortunately I didn't make a backup of the code and now that I'm trying to open the solution in Visual Studio 2019, I can't find my previous code and the application, which was in console, now only looks like a blank box that doesn't do anything of what it did before.

My goal is to retrieve my original code. I have tried disabling Avast antivirus, and even uninstalled Visual Studio 2019 to try to recover the code in Visual Studio 2017, but it did not work either. I hope you can help me.

This is the code that currently appears that bears no resemblance to my code.

```
// WindowsProject1.cpp : Define el punto de entrada de la aplicación.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "WindowsProject1.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Variables globales:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // instancia actual
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // Texto de la barra de título
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // nombre de clase de la ventana principal

// Declaraciones de funciones adelantadas incluidas en este módulo de código:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Colocar código aquí.

    // Inicializar cadenas globales
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Realizar la inicialización de la aplicación:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1));

    MSG msg;

    // Bucle principal de mensajes:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCIÓN: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PROPÓSITO: Registra la clase de ventana.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT1));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT1);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCIÓN: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PROPÓSITO: Guarda el identificador de instancia y crea la ventana principal
//
//   COMENTARIOS:
//
//        En esta función, se guarda el identificador de instancia en una variable común y
//        se crea y muestra la ventana principal del programa.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Almacenar identificador de instancia en una variable global

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCIÓN: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PROPÓSITO: Procesa mensajes de la ventana principal.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - procesar el menú de aplicaciones
//  WM_PAINT    - Pintar la ventana principal
//  WM_DESTROY  - publicar un mensaje de salida y volver
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Analizar las selecciones de menú:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Agregar cualquier código de dibujo que use hDC aquí...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Controlador de mensajes del cuadro Acerca de.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: If you did not save your original code, then it is gone, there is no recovering it.  Best you can do is reverse-engineer the app binary you have, but the result won't be exactly like the original code.

Comment: Ever heard of version control software such as GIT, TFS...

Comment: I'm very sad to read that, thank you very much for helping me. Could you recommend some tools to reverse-engineer my app to get a more approximate result?

Comment: My advice is backup the folder containing your project then look at the cpp files in your project folders directly.

Comment: @Alex097 It is not clear if you still have the .exe of your old app or not. If you do, you could try a search on the entire drive(s) for files having a last-modified timestamp around the same date/time as that .exe. If the old project and build files still exist somewhere on disk, this may point you to their location. Otherwise, search for *.vcxproj files and, if none found that matches what you remember then it's probably gone.

Comment: @dxiv Actually I still have that *.vcxproj file, what should I do with it?

Comment: @Alex097 Snoop around it (in the same directory and subdirectories) for .cpp files that may look like the one you lost. Also, open it in a text editor and check for references to .cpp files elsewhere. If neither try locates any files of interest chances are you overwrote or deleted the old .cpp and it's gone for good.